# Windows 2008 R2 does not keep ASP.NET Sessions using Server Name

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, internet-explorer

I already asked this question, with no suitable answer and I get getting the same problem on random servers.

I have an **ASP.NET 3.5 application** that is deployed using the Setup Project (MSI) and works fine in 90% of the installations, but time to time **I found a Windows 2008 Server that has this problem**.

I have a simple test that sets a session variable and reads from it.

This **never works on Internet Explorer** and I do have **cookies enabled** (for **Cookie Session**), but:

if I change the url from

`http://SERVER_NAME/APP_NAME/` to

`http://localhost/APP_NAME/` or `http://SERVER_IP/APP_NAME/` **everything works**!

And I can add that the SERVER_NAME is already in TRUSTED WEBSITES of IE

> **what can I do to fix this?**

Seams, at first sight a DNS problem, but it's a **intranet** site, as long as the Server has a DNS Server, it should work fine out-of-the-box, correct?

---

I **recreated this problem** using **HyperV** and Windows 2008 R2

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It isn't clear what the problem is here. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints about making questions easy to answer. Given this is about sessions: need to know what time period you are going back to the server and the server's app pool configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if an existing cookie is messing with the session cookie.  Try changing your sessionState settings to use a different cookie name and see if that helps.  And/or clear your cookies and restart the browser.  Also try removing it from the Intranet zone to prove whether or not it's from that.

Do you get the same with all browsers?  I guess if it's not IE you won't be in the Intranet zone so different browsers will probably have different results.

Comment: I did tried that, was one of my first thoughts, but this is very weird. I wonder if it's a DNS problem (thought I  tested with openDNS servers and flushed the cache) . then I remember ... wait, this is internally, should never go to outside DNS. :(
P.S. I still have this problem in 2 Windows 2008R2 Servers.

Comment: I should have asked, but is the error a session error, or does the page not even load with the servername?  If it doesn't load, the session part is a bunny trail and not the real issue.  If it does load but has session issues, try Firebug or Fiddler2 to see if you can narrow down any anomalies.